# Why is my windows HDD write protected?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, permissions, hex-editor

I am trying to modify the HDD that windows 7 is running on using WinHex. But after i edit a few bytes of the physical HDD, i cannot save the changes as it says my HDD is write protected and locked.

Is there anyway to actually edit a HDD in windows while windows is running? Please help

Comment: I've tried numerous disk editors and they all give me the same error about the HDD being write protected, so this isn't just a winhex issue.

Answer (score 2):

Open a command box and type in the following commands individually, and hit enter after each one.

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0 (or whatever disk you are trying to change)
attributes disk clear readonly (this command is not available on XP)
```

That should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Even `chkdsk` can not access a running `c:` drive. You need to boot from another disk/CD/USB Stick.

Other drives should work, as long as there is not a file open on the drive.

Comment: so basically its impossible?

Comment: No. I just used WinHex to clone a disk and it marked it write-protected as well. This is due to WinHex being used as a forensics tools. See KCotreau answer for a solution.